# Is there a way to make Mobs behave like in survival the same as they do in creative?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm playing minecraft with a younger player who is used to creative mode and he wants to play survival mode.

I'd like if we could attack mobs like creepers and zombies and have them not attack us.

Is there any way that would enable us to do this or something similar?

Comment: `/difficulty peaceful` removes all hostile mobs. Not exactly what you're asking, but may help some.

Comment: Related meta: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12357/what-sort-of-requests-for-external-resources-does-this-site-allow
Specifically: "if the question is asking for an external resource because the asker just assumes that that's how they should fix their problem, then it should be possible to edit it to be on-topic" It seems like the only reason this question is closed is because OP is asking for a *mod* instead of asking how to fix their problem (being able to attack mobs but not have them attack back). Shame

Comment: I have edited the question and attempted to honor author intent. I think this question could be reopened.

Comment: Thank you for editing it. I haven't been able to find a command that would do what I would like. I did find this MC Forum post about how to edit a mobs AI in a mod so I may end up writing my own.
http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/mapping-and-modding-tutorials/2281106-tutorial-how-to-change-an-existing-mobs-ai

Comment: Looks like the question is re-opened. If you find or create a solution, feel free to answer your own question below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make it where they can attack him, but he won't die easily. Put this command in:

`/effect @p minecraft:regeneration 100000 50`

That should make his hp regenerate fast enough that almost nothing can kill him excluding very high falls.

You can also add:

`/effect @p minecraft:health_boost 100000 50`

Which will give you a bunch of extra hearts making it even harder to die.

Comment: This looks great. I'll try it out.